# Need help to create my list in alphabetic order

Tags: c

I'm trying to create an alphabetically ordered linked list from a file by placing the node in the correct spot after reading it. The file must not be alphabetically ordered. The program reads the file correctly and I'm able to add everything at the end of the list.

```
Place search_place(Place first, char *new){

    Place aux = first;

    while (aux->abcnext != NULL){
        if ( strcmp(new,aux->place) > 0)
            aux = aux->abcnext;
        else
            break;
    }
    return aux;
}

void insert_place(Place first, char* string){

    Place previous,temp,new;

    previous = search_place(first, string);

    if (previous->abcnext == NULL){
        new = create_place();
        previous->place = string;
        new->abcnext = previous->abcnext;
        previous->abcnext = new;
    }

    else{
        new = (Place)malloc(sizeof(place_node));
        new->place = string;
        new->abcnext = previous;
        previous = new;
    }
}


Place create_place(){
    Place aux;
    aux=(Place)malloc(sizeof(place_node));

    if (aux!=NULL){
        aux->place=malloc(25*sizeof(char));
        aux->abcnext=NULL;
    }
    return aux;
}


typedef struct placenode*Place;

typedef struct placenode{
    char *place;
    Place abcnext;
}place_node;
```

Considering the results that I've obtained from this code I suppose the problem is related to either pointers or the header of the linked list or both. With 4 places: P, Z, W, L - I get only P -> Z from the list.

Comment: This code is incomplete. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56173948/i-need-help-in-adding-strings-alphabetically-in-a-linked-list

Answer (score 0):

```
if (previous->abcnext == NULL){
    new = create_place();
    previous->place = string;
    new->abcnext = previous->abcnext;
    previous->abcnext = new;
}
```

A couple of obvious problems with the above code. Firstly, you don't set `new->place` - you replace `previous->place` which doesn't seem right. So your new node will have NULL for it's "place" and you'll have lost the value for the previous node.

Secondly you're assigning the value of `string` rather than making a new copy. If you're using the same string each time you call the function, you'd end up with all the nodes pointing to the same string.

You should do something like

```
    new->place = malloc(strlen(string)+1);
    strcpy(new->place, string);
```

or if your version of C has it, use `strdup`

```
    new->place = strdup(string);
```

Comment: I applied your corrctions to my code but it did nothing, the problem is most likely when <previous->abcnext != NULL> and not when it is equal

Comment: Probably...that part of the code doesn't actually do anything except leak memory as you don't add the node into your list - `previous = new;` does absolutely nothing.